# Can't connect to postgres database from remote host using psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am unable to connect to postgres database through remote host using psycopg2 and getting the error like

Error:

```
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
     psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "192.x.x.x" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Note: I have made following changes

1.updated the pg_hba config file
host    all        all                 0.0.0.1/32               trust

2.updated the postgresql file
listen_addresses = '*'

3.changed the firewall rule to allow connection from port 5432
What else I have to do to make it work?

Comment: The error message suggest the client cannot reach the server so make sure **postgres** is listening on the needed interfaces: `sudo ss -lntp | grep 5432`. Did you restart the service after setting `listen_address`?

Comment: The range `0.0.0.1/32` contains only one host (*0.0.0.1*); I doubt this is the address you want to allow but this can be fixed after the TCP connection is OK.

Comment: "changed the firewall rule to allow connection from port 5432"  You need to allow connection **to** 5432.

Comment: yes, I have done

Comment: Can you post the results of `sudo ss -lntp | grep 5432` ? When you say "through remote host" are you referring to a tunneled connection or do you mean "from remote host"?

Comment: LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:5432                     *:*                   users:(("postgres",pid=28355,fd=4))
LISTEN     0      128        ::1:5432                    :::*                   users:(("postgres",pid=28355,fd=3)

Comment: from remote host

Comment: it is not showing 0.0.0.0:5432 but i have made changes to pg_hba file as 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: i have installed postgres in rhel7

Comment: The `ss` output indicates the service is only listening on localhost; to change that you need to edit `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf` and restart the service; `pg_hba` has no effect on that.

Comment: i have put list_address to '*' then also showing the same thing

Comment: Make sure the `listen_addresses = '*'` line is not commented in the config file; are you sure you are restarting the service correctly? What's the output of `ps aux | grep postgres`? Use something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to paste it.

Comment: thanks alot, it was silly mistake, that listen address line was commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others that might encounter the same issue, here are some things you can try.

**Make sure the service is listening on the needed interfaces**

```
sudo ss -lntp | grep 5432
```

If you see something like `127.0.0.1:5432` or `::1:5432` this means **localhost**.
Tweak **[postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html)**:

```
listen_addresses='192.168.1.2, 127.0.0.1'
```

You can also use **'*'** which means any interface but depending on your network configuration it might be dangerous.
Make sure the `listen_addresses` line isn't commented (as was the case above) and **restart** the service after making changes.

**Check your firewall configuration**
After making sure the service is listening on the correct interface make sure your **firewall**(s), if any, permit the client to connect to the service (this can mean your local firewall, a network device sitting between the client and the service).

**Check [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)**
This file controls PostgreSQL's host-based authentication mechanism:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             192.168.1.3/32          md5
```

The line above allows all users to connect from `192.168.1.3` if they provide the required password; if you want to allow a whole subnet you can use something like `192.168.1.0/24`.

If you suspect an issue with **psycopg2** or **Python** you can test the connectivity using PostgreSQL's client: psql:
`psql -U postgres -h 192.168.1.2 db_name`

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)